# Flash Catalyst TextInput

Tags: apache-flex, flash, textinput

I have an issue with creating a specific TextInput (text field) component in Flash Catalyst.

Here is how I want my TextInput component to behave:

1. When the TextInput component is in it's "normal" state, I want it to be with a black stroke.
2. When it's being clicked (for typing), I want the component to have a green stroke and a green  glow.
3. When the component is deselected, I want it to have a black stroke as in it's normal state, and naturally, the text should remain visible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to attach event listeners (FocusEvent.FOCUS, FocusEvent.BLUR) to change the `graphics` property of the `TextInput` conditionally - that is, the property will be assigned a `Sprite` (or similar) that has had the effects you mentioned applied to or drawn on it.